# maven bundle plugin configuration

Tags: java, maven, osgi, bundle, manifest

I'm generating the manifest file using maven bundle plugin.
This is my configuration  :

```
      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
          <extensions>true</extensions>
          <configuration>
              <instructions>
                  <_wab>src/main/webapp</_wab>
                  <Import-Package>org.osgi.framework,javax.servlet, javax.servlet.http</Import-Package>
                  <Export-Package></Export-Package>
                  <Bundle-Version>2</Bundle-Version>
                  <Bundle-SymbolicName>fr.lyon1.Client</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                  <Bundle-ClassPath>.,WEB-INF/classes</Bundle-ClassPath>
                  <Web-ContextPath>/client</Web-ContextPath>
              </instructions>
          </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

This is an example of generated file :

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bnd-LastModified: 1384018413590
Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_45
Built-By: houssem
Bundle-ClassPath: WEB-INF/classes,.,WEB-INF/classes
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: client Maven Webapp
Bundle-SymbolicName: fr.lyon1.Client
Bundle-Version: 2
Created-By: Apache Maven Bundle Plugin
Import-Package: javax.servlet,javax.servlet.http,org.osgi.framework;vers
 ion="[1.5,2)"
Tool: Bnd-2.1.0.20130426-122213
Web-ContextPath: /client
```

The problem is that in the Bundle-ClassPath, the plugin add automaticly "WEB-INF/classes".

How can I prevent it from generating this ?

Even if I change my configuration to 
.
It generate this : 
Bundle-ClassPath: WEB-INF/classes,.

I want to have the . before WEB-INF/classes

Thank you & sorry for my english =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The _wab instruction tells bundle plugin (bnd) that you want to have your classpath structured like a WAR file, i.e. with `WEB-INF/classes` followed by `WEB-INF/lib/*.jar`.

Therefore if you want to use "." as your bundle classpath then just remove the _wab instruction.

However if you do this, be aware that your bundle will no longer be a valid WAR file according to the J2EE standards. So although it will deploy just fine into an OSGi Framework, it will not deploy into a traditional J2EE server or web container like Tomcat. This may not be important if you have already coupled the internals of the bundle to OSGi APIs such as `BundleContext` etc.